# How to insert image into database in Java

Tags: java

I want to insert image into database through a "browse" button. What is the problem in this line, `ps.setBlob(l16, inputStream)`? This line shows an error every time.

My code is:

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(  
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/hostel_management","root","");  

PreparedStatement ps= con.prepareStatement("insert into student_info values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");  

ps.setString(1, tf1.getText());
ps.setString(2, tf2.getText());
.
.
.
ps.setString(15, tf15.getText());

InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(tf16.getText()));

ps.setBlob(16, inputStream);

ps.execute(); 

JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Successfully Inserted", "Message", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);

con.close();
```

Comment: "This line shows an error every time" What is the error message?

Comment: Have  you verified the parameter order?

Comment: Try `ps.setBlob(16, inputStream, (int)fileLength);`

Comment: It will probably be easier to just save the image into a dedicated folder and keep a name of the file in DB.

Comment: Thnks saka1029, problem has solved :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the image into Base64, and just save it as a text into your database. When you want it back, get it and revert it into bitmap and use it.

Use Apache commons to do it at best way

```
Base64.encode(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
```

For decoding it,

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decode(image.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT));
```

Where image is a string contains Base64 text.
Let me know if you want more help.

Comment: Why would you do it like that?  Storing arbitrary binary data like the op is trying to do is exactly what blob columns are for

Comment: Blob is internally handled like a string. So it ofcourse make sense.

Comment: TEXT and CHAR will convert to/from the character set they have associated with time. BLOB and BINARY simply store bytes.

BLOB is used for storing binary data while Text is used to store large string.

BLOB values are treated as binary strings (byte strings). They have no character set, and sorting and comparison are based on the numeric values of the bytes in column values.

TEXT values are treated as nonbinary strings (character strings). They have a character set, and values are sorted and compared based on the collation of the character set.

Comment: How blobs are handled is up to the db implementation. And I'm not sure how you can seriously suggest that jamming images into a text field when there's already a field for binary data makes any sense. That's like storing numbers as varchar. Sure, you can do it, but it's an awful idea.

Comment: Yes it is an awful idea, but I am just giving a possibility!

Answer (score -1):

Best way will be to store the image in a folder and save the path of that image into the database. Saving Blob or Clob objects into database is too time consuming and can cause inefficiency in some cases.

Comment: This should be a comment. it is not an answer to the question.

Comment: That's extremely vague. And probably wrong too. In any case, storing paths in a database is completely pointless, how would you ever get to the image then?

Comment: When you store path into database, you just put the path in the html code, in img tag - src parameter. Image will automatically be fetched using http on the clients browser, from the server.

url in database looks something like - "http://servername.com/somefolder/uniqueimagename.jpg", and your html img tag looks like this - <img class="myimage" src="<%=homeBean.getURL()%>"/>, if you are using jsp servlet, and will look like this - <img class="myimage" src="<?php $imgurl?>"/>. Please let me know if I am wrong somewhere.